# How can I have a space in user inputted variable for bat script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy, robocopy

I have made a small bat file for creating pre-built folders with user inputted name. It works fine until a user inputs a variable with a space. For example - the user inputting "John" would create a folder with sub folders called John (exactly what we want), however if a user was to enter Smith, John, the folder created will be called Smith,. How can I allow the script to register the user inputted space?

My code -

```
@echo off

set /P dest=Enter Name: 
set findest="Z:\ProjectIT\copy\%dest%"

robocopy Z:\ProjectIT\copy\xcopy "%findest
```

I understand this is probably an easy fix but I have a very limited knowledge of code.

Thanks

Comment: use the variable with `%findest%` - and delete the Quote before, your variable already contains all quotes that it Needs.

Comment: Let me recommend to use the syntax `set "VAR=Value"` for _all_ your `set` commands in general; this avoids trouble with special characters, but does _not_ include the quotes in the `Value`; so there is always _one_ place to take care of surrounding quotes -- the _expansion_ of `"%VAR%"`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highly recommended suggestions by [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) and [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) applied to your code:

```
@echo off

set /P "dest=Enter name: "
set "findest=Z:\ProjectIT\copy\%dest%"

%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe Z:\ProjectIT\copy\xcopy "%findest%"
```

See for example answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) for an explanation why `set "VAR=Value"` on assignment and `"%VAR%"` on expansion/reference is highly recommended even if the string to assign to a variable contains 1 more quotes.

Here is also an improved version which allows the string to be entered with double quotes and with each `/` (Linux/Mac directory separator) replaced by `\` (Windows directory separator) and which removes last backslash from destination path because of **ROBOCOPY** interprets a single backslash at end of a directory path as escape character for the double quote:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:EnterName
set "dest=""
set /P "dest=Enter name: "
set "dest=%dest:"=%"
if not defined dest cls & goto EnterName
set "dest=%dest:/=\%"
if "%dest:~-1%" == "\" set "dest=%dest:~0,-1%"
if not defined dest cls & goto EnterName

set "findest=Z:\ProjectIT\copy\%dest%"

%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe Z:\ProjectIT\copy\xcopy "%findest%"
endlocal
```